# How to pass an arraylist to the Constructor

Tags: java

I'm a beginner at java and I am trying to do a program to introduce myself. 
Below is my script.

```
    class Description 
    { 
    // Instance variable 
    private String name, national, dob;
    private ArrayList<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();  

    public Description()
    {

    }

    // Other Constructor 
    public Description(String name, String national, String dob)
    {
        this.name = name; 
        this.national = national;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    // Copy Constructor 


    // Accessor Method
    private String getname()
    {
        return name; 
    }

    private String getnational()
    {
        return national; 
    }

    private String getdob()
    {
        return dob;
    }

    private ArrayList geHobbies(){
        return hobbies;
    }

    // Mutator Method
    public void setHobbies(ArrayList hobbies)
    {
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }



    public void printInfo()
    {   
        System.out.println("My Information");
        System.out.printf("Name: %s%n", getname()); 
        System.out.printf("National: %s%n", getnational());
        System.out.printf("Date of birth: %s%n", getdob());

        System.out.printf("I have %d hobbies %n", hobbies.size());
        System.out.printf("  1: %s%n", hobbies.get(0));
        System.out.printf("  2: %s%n", hobbies.get(1));
    }
}
```

Main class:-

```
    class Lab_1 
    {

        public static void main (String [] args)
        {

            Description ds = new Description("Daniel ", "Singapore",  "01-01-2020"); 
            ArrayList <Description> hobbies = new ArrayList <Description> ();
            hobbies.add("Studying");
            hobbies.add("Coding");

            ds.printInfo();

        }
    }
```

However I received `error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Description` when I tried to run the script. Can any expert out there guide me on how I can solve this issue. Thank you! I am also required to create another arraylist call wishes, and include 4 wishes. while I'm still stuck at hobbies, I can't proceed and work on the other arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You got the error because you are trying to add strings to the `ArrayList` but the `ArrayList` has not been declared to store `String` values.

Replace

```
ArrayList <Description> hobbies = new ArrayList <> ();
```

with

```
ArrayList <String> hobbies = new ArrayList <> ();
```

and then do the following

```
hobbies.add("Studying");
hobbies.add("Coding");
ds.setHobbies(hobbies);
```

Comment: It would be better idea to use diamond operator in declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a `String` object (`"Studying"`) to a collection that holds `Description` objects. Square peg, round hole.

The error message `String cannot be converted to Description` is quite clear on this matter.

This:

```
    Description ds = new Description("Ron ", "Singapore",  "01-01-2020"); 
    ArrayList <Description> hobbies = new ArrayList <Description> ();
    hobbies.add("Studying");
```

…should be:

```
    Description ds = new Description("Ron ", "Singapore",  "01-01-2020"); 

    ArrayList <Description> descriptions = new ArrayList <Description> ();
    descriptions.add( ds ) ;
```

To add a list of hobbies to the `Description` object, pass the list to the `setHobbies` method you wrote.

```
    Description ds = new Description("Ron ", "Singapore",  "01-01-2020"); 
    List< String > hobbies = List.of( "Studying" , "Coding" ) ;
    ds.setHobbies( hobbies ) ;

    ArrayList <Description> descriptions = new ArrayList <Description> ();
    descriptions.add( ds ) ;
```

We can tighten up that code.

```
    Description ds = new Description( "Ron " , "Singapore" ,  "01-01-2020" ) ; 
    ds.setHobbies( List.of( "Studying" , "Coding" ) ) ;

    List < Description > descriptions = new ArrayList <> () ;
    descriptions.add( ds ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding hobbies of `string` type to `Description` Type.

```
ArrayList <Description> hobbies = new ArrayList <Description> ();
```

Change it to String and then set these hobbies with the object ds of `Description`

```
  ArrayList<String> hobbies=new ArrayList<String>(); // Create ArrayList of type String not Description
  hobbies.add("Studying");
  hobbies.add("Coding");
  ds.setHobbies(hobbies); // set the hobbies with the description object
  ds.printInfo();
```

OUTPUT:-

```
My Information
Name: Ron 
National: Singapore
Date of birth: 01-01-2020
I have 2 hobbies 
  1: Studying
  2: Coding
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hobbies object is suppose to be of type `ArrayList<String>`
To it pass to your Description class constructor you can do it like this

```java
// Other Constructor 
public Description(String name, String national, String dob,ArrayList<String> hobbies)
{
    this.name = name; 
    this.national = national;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.hobbies=hobbies;
}
```

Here is your full class with constructor changes

```java
class Description 
{ 
// Instance variable 
private String name, national, dob;
private ArrayList<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<String>();  

public Description()
{

}

// Other Constructor 
public Description(String name, String national, String dob,ArrayList<String> hobbies)
{
    this.name = name; 
    this.national = national;
    this.dob = dob;
    this.hobbies=hobbies;
}

// Copy Constructor 


// Accessor Method
private String getname()
{
    return name; 
}

private String getnational()
{
    return national; 
}

private String getdob()
{
    return dob;
}

private ArrayList geHobbies(){
    return hobbies;
}

// Mutator Method
public void setHobbies(ArrayList hobbies)
{
    this.hobbies = hobbies;
}



public void printInfo()
{   
    System.out.println("My Information");
    System.out.printf("Name: %s%n", getname()); 
    System.out.printf("National: %s%n", getnational());
    System.out.printf("Date of birth: %s%n", getdob());

    System.out.printf("I have %d hobbies %n", hobbies.size());
    System.out.printf("  1: %s%n", hobbies.get(0));
    System.out.printf("  2: %s%n", hobbies.get(1));
}
}
```

Here is your main Method

```java
public static void main(String []args){

        ArrayList <String> hobbies = new ArrayList <String> ();
        hobbies.add("Studying");
        hobbies.add("Coding");
        Description ds = new Description("Ron ", "Singapore",  "01-01-2020", hobbies); 
        ds.printInfo();
     }
```

Comment: Alright thank you for the help,  However I still have another question. While the Java allows me to run the program but it prompted me with an error                                                 "Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details." May I ask if you know why? Thank You!